# How to get file from Form Data in the server

Tags: php, sql, angular, ionic-framework

I cant get the file data on the server. _$FILE says is empty. I do this trough ionic app. I send the information in  http params.

```
cargarFoto(idnegocio,formData) {
    let datos = new HttpParams()
    .set("proceso", "subirImgNegocioApp")
    .set("imgRestaurante", formData)
    .set("idnegocio", idnegocio)

    let headerOptions = new HttpHeaders().set('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
    return this.http.post(this.path,datos, {
      observe: 'response',
      responseType: 'text',
      headers: headerOptions
    });
  }
```

That is the code from my service where i send the form Data and other information.
But when i use $_FILES to get the file, it says is null or empty. What im doing wrong? Actually all the information is get on $_POST. I returned post to the app and this is what displays:

body: "{
"proceso": "subirImgNegocioApp",
"imgRestaurante": "[object FormData]",
"idnegocio": "4"
}"

Comment: Wrong `Content-Type` for a file upload request.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can suggest little different approach - send everything as form data:

```
  sendSomething(someVar: string, files: File[]) {
    const formData = new FormData();
    for (const f of files) {
      formData.append('file[]', f);
    }
    formData.append('someVar', someVar);
    return this.http.post('/someUrl', formData, {
      headers: new HttpHeaders({ enctype: 'multipart/form-data' })
    });
  }
```

Then in PHP:

```
$someVar = $_REQUEST['someVar']
```

And files (or one file) will be in

```
$_FILES['file']
```